# Virtualbox: host Ubuntu -> guest XP from time to time copy/paste stop to work

Tags: virtualbox

Sometime after host rebooting and always after Virtualbox updating copy/paste from host Ubuntu to guest XP stops to work. After next reboot it usually work as expected. Rebooting guest does not help. Switching "share clipboard" on-off does not help. Rebooting host is usually something to avoid. 
Can I fix somehow the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite old, really unsresolved bug about this --- see [this comment on the virtualbox issue tracker](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5266#comment:144). There is even a still-open bug [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5815).

I think that the resolution has been not to fix it for XP. A workaround is stopping and restarting `VBoxTray.exe` in XP. Working partially; more info here on [superuser.sx](https://superuser.com/questions/536827/virtualbox-bidirectional-clipboard-sharing-stops-working-after-some-time).

What I used to do was using the Task Manager in Windows XP, killing the `VBoxTray.exe` process, and then start it again (with the "run..." option in the Start menu, typing the program name is usually sufficient). Works again during a time, then stops...